# Why when I want to modify the scale with "" it comes to a certain scale and then starts gobbling up the content

Tags: html, css, resize, media-queries

**It is assumed that the page consists of a left section and a right section**

**And I want when the screen is reduced to a certain width, the left section disappears, and the right section to mediate the entire page**

**You will find the below blocks of code to see what I'm talking about:**

It is assumed that the page consists of a left section and a right section

And I want when the screen is reduced to a certain width, the left section disappears, and the right section mediates the entire page

you will find the below blocks of code to see what I'm talking about :

### HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- reset-style-sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <!-- main-style-sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <!-- google fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- font-awsome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="csss/all.min.css" />
    <title>Invision sign-up page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
      <div class="left">
        <div class="top">
          <img src="img/5553ef310fb0f4a52c8ed204990684da.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="bot">
          <p>
            “Having a digital space to brainstorm your ideas gives everyone a
            voice. Using the brainstorming template gave everyone equal input.”
          </p>
          <div class="box">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i>
            <img src="img/4e221e58addbc2f5158cad37399b7873.png" alt="" />
            <div class="h4">megan sempre</div>
          </div>
          <h4>senior designer at xbox</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="box">
          <h4>get startd absolutly free</h4>
          <p>already have an invision account? <a href="#">sign in</a></p>
          <form action="" id="form_id">
            <label for="email">work email address</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              placeholder="enter your work email and we will search for teams you can join"
            />
            <label for="name">your name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" required />
            <label for="role">your role</label>
            <select id="role" required>
              <option value="select your role">select your role</option>
              <option value="design">design</option>
              <option value="product mangment">product mangment</option>
              <option value="human resources/people ops">
                human resources/people ops
              </option>
              <option value="recruting">recruting</option>
              <option value="finance/accounting">finance/accounting</option>
              <option value="customer">customer</option>
              <option value="educator">educator</option>
              <option value="student">student</option>
              <option value="other">other</option>
            </select>
            <label for="pass">password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="pass"
              placeholder="6+ characters"
              required
            />
          </form>
          <button type="submit" form="form_id">sign up</button>
          <p>
            By signing up, I agree to InVision's
            <a href="#">terms of service</a> and <a href="#">privacy policy</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### css :

```
/* start var */
:root {
  --main-color: #75391e;
  --secnd-color: #f1ebe8;
  --therd-color: #a49e9c;
}
/* end var */
/* start global ruls */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto";
}

.containatr {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* small */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .containatr {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
/* meduim */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .containatr {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
/* large */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .containatr {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
/* end global ruls */
.page {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
.page .logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 20px;
}
.page .left {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1977d2;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.page .left .top {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.page .left .top img {
  width: 400px;
  /* max-width: 60vw; */
}
.page .left .bot {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.page .left .bot p {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.page .left .bot .box {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2vh 0 1.5vh;
}
.page .left .bot img {
  width: 50px;
}
.page .left .bot .box i {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  left: 43px;
  top: 7px;
}
.page .left .bot .box .h4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 60px;
  background-color: #f94578;
  color: white;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 7px 17px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -ms-border-radius: 25px;
  -o-border-radius: 25px;
}
.page .left .bot h4 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.page .right {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  height: 100vh;
}
.page .right h4 {
  color: #1d1d1f;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.page .right p {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.page .right p a {
  color: #1d1d1f;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
}
.page .right .box form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.page .right .box form label {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 20px 0 5px;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.page .right .box form input {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0.1px solid rgb(163, 163, 163);
  outline: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
}
.page .right .box form input::placeholder {
  font-size: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.page .right .box form select {
  position: relative;
  color: #a3a3a3;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 0.1px solid #a3a3a3;
  outline: 0;
}
.page .right .box form input:hover,
.page .right .box form select:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(92, 92, 92);
}
.page .right .box form input:focus,
.page .right .box form select:focus {
  border: 1px solid rgb(53, 60, 238);
}
.page .right .box button {
  cursor: no-drop;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f2f2f3;
  color: #7e7e86;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.page .right .box button:required {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #1977d2;
  color: white;
}
.page .right .box p:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #7e7e89;
}
.page .right .box p:last-of-type a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.page .right .box p:last-of-type a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
@media (max-width: 771px) {
  .left {
    display: none;
  }
  .page {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .page .right .box form {
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is the corrected code, see if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

add the following in your css:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
      .page {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
      }
      .page .left {
        display: none;
      }
      .page .right {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    }
```

```css
/* start var */
:root {
  --main-color: #75391e;
  --secnd-color: #f1ebe8;
  --therd-color: #a49e9c;
}
/* end var */
/* start global ruls */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto";
}

.containatr {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* small */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .containatr {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
/* meduim */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .containatr {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
/* large */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .containatr {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
/* end global ruls */
.page {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
.page .logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 20px;
}
.page .left {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1977d2;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.page .left .top {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.page .left .top img {
  width: 400px;
  /* max-width: 60vw; */
}
.page .left .bot {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.page .left .bot p {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.page .left .bot .box {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2vh 0 1.5vh;
}
.page .left .bot img {
  width: 50px;
}
.page .left .bot .box i {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  left: 43px;
  top: 7px;
}
.page .left .bot .box .h4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 60px;
  background-color: #f94578;
  color: white;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 7px 17px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -ms-border-radius: 25px;
  -o-border-radius: 25px;
}
.page .left .bot h4 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.page .right {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  height: 100vh;
}
.page .right h4 {
  color: #1d1d1f;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.page .right p {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.page .right p a {
  color: #1d1d1f;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
}
.page .right .box form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.page .right .box form label {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 20px 0 5px;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.page .right .box form input {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0.1px solid rgb(163, 163, 163);
  outline: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
}
.page .right .box form input::placeholder {
  font-size: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.page .right .box form select {
  position: relative;
  color: #a3a3a3;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 0.1px solid #a3a3a3;
  outline: 0;
}
.page .right .box form input:hover,
.page .right .box form select:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(92, 92, 92);
}
.page .right .box form input:focus,
.page .right .box form select:focus {
  border: 1px solid rgb(53, 60, 238);
}
.page .right .box button {
  cursor: no-drop;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f2f2f3;
  color: #7e7e86;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.page .right .box button:required {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #1977d2;
  color: white;
}
.page .right .box p:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #7e7e89;
}
.page .right .box p:last-of-type a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.page .right .box p:last-of-type a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .page {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .page .left {
    display: none;
  }
  .page .right {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- reset-style-sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <!-- main-style-sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <!-- google fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- font-awsome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="csss/all.min.css" />
    <title>Invision sign-up page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
      <div class="left">
        <div class="top">
          <img src="img/5553ef310fb0f4a52c8ed204990684da.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="bot">
          <p>
            “Having a digital space to brainstorm your ideas gives everyone a
            voice. Using the brainstorming template gave everyone equal input.”
          </p>
          <div class="box">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i>
            <img src="img/4e221e58addbc2f5158cad37399b7873.png" alt="" />
            <div class="h4">megan sempre</div>
          </div>
          <h4>senior designer at xbox</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="box">
          <h4>get startd absolutly free</h4>
          <p>already have an invision account? <a href="#">sign in</a></p>
          <form action="" id="form_id">
            <label for="email">work email address</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              placeholder="enter your work email and we will search for teams you can join"
            />
            <label for="name">your name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" required />
            <label for="role">your role</label>
            <select id="role" required>
              <option value="select your role">select your role</option>
              <option value="design">design</option>
              <option value="product mangment">product mangment</option>
              <option value="human resources/people ops">
                human resources/people ops
              </option>
              <option value="recruting">recruting</option>
              <option value="finance/accounting">finance/accounting</option>
              <option value="customer">customer</option>
              <option value="educator">educator</option>
              <option value="student">student</option>
              <option value="other">other</option>
            </select>
            <label for="pass">password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="pass"
              placeholder="6+ characters"
              required
            />
          </form>
          <button type="submit" form="form_id">sign up</button>
          <p>
            By signing up, I agree to InVision's
            <a href="#">terms of service</a> and <a href="#">privacy policy</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```